# Img.show() showing error In Python pillow

Tags: python, image, import, python-imaging-library, typeerror

This is the code

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('hi.png')
im.show()
```

Error msg is here

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kd/Documents/python/modules/pillow_image.py", line 3, in <module>
    im.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2146, in show
    _show(self, title=title, command=command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3085, in _show
    _showxv(image, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3091, in _showxv
    ImageShow.show(image, title, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 47, in show
    if viewer.show(image, title=title, **options):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 67, in show
    return self.show_image(image, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 87, in show_image
    return self.show_file(self.save_image(image), **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py", line 168, in show_file
    subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 858, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1639, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _posixsubprocess.fork_exec(
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
[Finished in 178ms with exit code 1]
```

It should open the image in imageviewer in linux but I am geting this error

Comment: I'm using Pillow version 9.5.0 and it opens the image for me.

Comment: i am using pillow 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Pillow version do you have? I encounter this problem some time ago, on older version when .show() method would result in this error if no title was given. Try using:

```
...
im.show(title="some title")
```

Comment: thank you sir❤️..perfect..it worked like magic..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely the directory and the fact that you are missing the "r". If it is in the same folder as your python file use

```
im = Image.open(r'hi.png')
```

If it's in a diffrent folder use the whole directory for exemple:

```
im = Image.open(r'C:\Users\System-Pc\Desktop\hi.png')
```

Comment: did not work :-( showing the same error after using r...and yeah it is in the same folder...I guess the problem is only with the line "im.show()" ..cause I can print the details of the picture using   ''print(im)''